# In Plone, how do I fix Archetypes content that is missing the cmf_uid() annotation?

Tags: plone

I'm using Plone 4.3 with relstorage and I've somehow managed to lose the `cmf_uid` annotation on some of my content objects. This prevents `collective.iterate` from being able to check in content. Is there an easy way to have Plone walk through the database and re-add `cmf_uid` where it is missing? Already tried `collective.catalogcleanup` to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a script that searches the portal (passed as `context`) for any `Document` that has a non-unique `cmf_uid`. Many of these documents actually have no `cmf_uid` but the indexed `cmf_uid` actually comes from the parent folder via `Acquisition`. Since the manifestation of the problem was that `plone.app.iterate` was unable to check in `Document`, the script adds a unique `cmf_uid` to just the `Document` types that appear to have non-unique `cmf_uid` but actually have no `cmf_uid`.

Although this adds `cmf_uid` to all `Document`, it would probably be sufficient to only add the attribute to documents currently being edited in checkouts.

```
"""
Add missing cmf_uid to Archetypes content.

cmf_uid is required to check in working copies of content.
"""

from Products.CMFUid.UniqueIdHandlerTool import UniqueIdError
from Acquisition import aq_inner
from collections import Counter

def add_missing_uids(context):
    """
    context: the portal
    """
    portal_uidhandler = context.portal_uidhandler
    portal_uidgenerator = context.portal_uidgenerator
    catalog = context.portal_catalog
    brains = catalog.unrestrictedSearchResults()
    freq = Counter(x.cmf_uid for x in brains)
    for brain in brains:
        # If it's only in use once then it's unique enough. Otherwise it's
        # probably inheriting its indexed cmf_uid via Acquisition.
        if freq[brain.cmf_uid] < 2 or brain.portal_type != 'Document':
            continue
        ob = aq_inner(brain.getObject())
        if not portal_uidhandler.queryUid(ob):
            print brain.Type, brain.portal_type, brain.getPath()
            for i in range(3):
                try:
                    portal_uidhandler.setUid(ob, portal_uidgenerator())
                    ob.reindexObject()
                    ob.reindexObject(idxs=['modified'])
                    break
                except UniqueIdError:
                    print "RETRY"
            else:
                print "FAIL"
```